# Can I reference a query generated at run time in the DCount function?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to use function DCount("[fieldname]", "qryname") to count the number of records returned from a dynamic query that I am creating in a private Sub.  In my Sub I am doing something like this

```
    Private Sub getRecs(ByVal stype, ByVal whichrecs, ByVal sorder)
      Dim x as String
      x = "SQL statement...
        .
        .
        .
      "
      Me.RecordSource = x
      Me.Requery
    End Sub
```

The query is created at run time so I can't save it ahead of time and reference like DCount("[fieldname]", "qryname").

I have tried referencing inside the Sub like this

```
tcount = DCount("[fieldname]", "x")
tcount = DCount("[fieldname]", "Me")
tcount = DCount("[fieldname]", x)
tcount = DCount("[fieldname]", Me)
```

The first two attempt result in error message Run time 3078 - access cant find query called "x" or "Me".  Without the quotes, the error is Run time 3163 - the field is too small to accept the amount of data attempted to add.

Can I reference a query generated at run time in the DCount function?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any particular reason why you want to use DCount? An alternative like this should work:

```
Function CountValues(SelectStatement As String, FieldName As String) As Long
  Dim RS As Recordset
  Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Count(" + FieldName + ") FROM (" + SelectStatement + ")")
  CountValues = RS(0) 
End Function
```

Hence:

```
tcount = CountValues(Me.RecordSource, "[fieldname]")
```

Comment: very nice, this is a nice alternative to my thinking.